# Apex - Variable declaration

Tags: apex

I have declared boolean variable as:

Boolean x;

Initially variable x will hold true or false - what will be default value for x?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: It will take 5 seconds to verify in dev console:) btw it's null ...

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean are tri-valued true, false and null(default)

Answer (score 0):

From The documentation [variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm)

> ### Null Variables and Initial Values
>
> If you declare a variable and don't initialize it with a value, it will be null. In essence, null means the absence of a value. You can also assign null to any variable declared with a primitive type.